# Data transformation using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a csv file in which there are two variables . I have to add these two variables:- like salary and bonus(in which the salary is comma seperated), but it is not happening in the pig.I tried using the casting also. below is the screenshot of the dataset:-

[image]

I used  the below pig script:-

```
register /home/ravimishra/piggybank-0.15.0.jar;
define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
emp_details_header = LOAD 'data/employee.csv' USING CSVLoader  AS (id: int, name: chararray, address: chararray, occupation: chararray,salary: chararray,bonus: double);
ranked = rank emp_details_header;
NoHeader = Filter ranked by (rank_emp_details_header > 1);
B = FOREACH NoHeader GENERATE id,name,address,occupation, (double)salary + bonus as total   ;
```

Comment: Make sure the path is correct.Dump the loaded data to see if the comma in the salary is removed,else use replace to remove the comma from the salary field.Finally enclose the sum with additional () i.e. ((double)salary + bonus)

Comment: How to remove the comma, I tried using REPLACE function but not able to remove.

Comment: Can you try this once ((double)(REPLACE(salary, ',' ,'')) + bonus). Also if you can paste the output when you are running the above script.

Comment: Thanks Suranjan, Now it is working.